# iOS UIPageControl Replace Status Bar

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I am wondering how you would replace the status bar or at least place the page control over it?  This would be a temporary placement for a couple seconds each time someone pages then it will disappear.  I have seen it in apps before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you cant get above the statusbar as it doesn't belong to your root-window.

But can call this to remove the UIStatusBar manually even with animation option.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

You can also disable it in your window in InterfaceBuilder. Or you can add the key `Status bar is initially hidden = YES` in your `appname-Info.plist` file.

Then you can do with the space what you want.

Maybe you want to remove it and then let it appear again, but be aware that your root-window-size will change due to the 20 pixel you gain from the hidden statusbar.